# Need change background color

Tags: linux, unix, terminal, operating-system

I should change background-color of terminal in linux mint cinnamon, but how can I do it?, But I tried change color, and I did it, but I couldn't know how to change Background-color...

Comment: `tput setab $color` where `color` is a digit from 0 to 9

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Go to Menu – Edit – Profile – Edit – General tab. In this tab you can change the font. Then go to the tab – Colors. Remove the check mark from the "Use colors from system theme".